# Reading in a list from a file and Assigning values to specific columns

Tags: python

Below is an example of a file I am reading in. I want to be able to assign each value in every column to its own column. So for example column[1] = "number1" and contain all of the first column values and so on.

```
with open("datafile") as datafile:
next(datafile)
for line in datafile:
    datafile_line = line.split(",")
    print(datafile_line)

number1  number2       number3       number4       number5      number6
 8068   0.45230480   0.88468528    1.843e-007    -6.589e-008     4.01
22109   1.24573974  -0.05680449    8.386e-008     -6.55e-008     4.01
34088   1.85052401   0.35901941   -2.962e-008    -4.654e-009     4.01
35037   1.89722047  -0.46727120   -6.245e-008     3.719e-008     4.01
71865   3.84827581  -0.65962098   -1.814e-007    -1.487e-007     4.01
78527   4.19703294   1.02215647   -2.975e-006     1.624e-006     4.01
```

Comment: I have tried putting it into a list but I am not quite sure how to do that correctly, it just puts it into one really long line. I want to go line by line and select just the first value and save it. I am reading line by line currently but do not know how to search that line

Answer (score 0):

So what it sounds like you want to do is transform the "rows" of the file into a *column* representation.

```
f = open('/tmp/data.txt', 'r')
cols = []
for line in f:
    line = line.replace('\t', ' ')
    col = line.split(sep=' ')
    col = [ x for x in col if x != '' and x != ' ']
    col = list(zip(range(0,len(col)), col))
    for tup in col:
        index, value = tup
        if len(cols) <= index:
            cols.append([])
        cols[index].append(value.strip())

print(cols)
```

This code will read in the file contents, assuming it is called `/tmp/data.txt` and split each line on whitespace. For each non-whitespace word in the input, it will create a list in the `cols` variable and build up each of the *column* values as it traverses the file.